# Check if any number is repeated, individually, more than N times

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

What I want to check is if there is any number repated more than 5 times with a regex.

I have looked through some other questions, and the suggestion they make is this one `/([0-9]{5}\1)/`. But this one matches any 5 numbers together.

What I want to achieve with this regex is finding if, for example, number 1 is repeated 5 times, number 2, number 3 and so on.

Is there any way to achieve this via regex or should I make a loop for all values?

**Expected outputs:**

`112113` false

`911111` true

`112111` false

`222223` true

Comment: I think it should be like this `([0-9])\1{4}` to repeat the same number 5 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern `([0-9]{5}\1)` uses a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html) to a group that does not exist yet.

In Javascript you will match 5 consecutive digits as according to the documentation stated at the link to the backreference

> According to the official ECMA standard, a backreference to a
>   non-participating capturing group must successfully match nothing..

You could update your pattern to put the capturing group around matching a single digit and then repeat that 4 times to match 5 repeated digits.

```
([0-9])\1{4}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QdoVbK/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use filter. It is faster than regex. In the function input the number, the number whose repentance has to be calculated and the number of times the repetition has to be found. Convert the number to a string and split it into an array. Apply filter and for the occurrence of the number. It will return an array. If the length of the array is equal to the number of repentance than return true else false

```js
var n = 1;
var num = 1123231121;
var comp = 5

function a(n, num, comp) {
  console.log(String(num).split('').filter(function(e) {
return e == n
  }).length == comp)
}
a(n, num, comp)
```

Comment: Don't think this will work with `222223` unless it's repeated for each digit (0-9)

Comment: No it wont, because we are giving the number as a parameter for which it has to check the repentance. If we provide 2 for the given number then 222223 will return true

Comment: I am sorry, I edited the wrong answer. It should be back as before, but please have a check. Sorry for the edit.